# Bitwise operation between two byte(8 bit hex) getting error in C#

Tags: c#, hex, byte, bitwise-operators

I am getting error in this C# code from 2nd & 3rd line

```
byte Data = 0x00;
Data = Data | 0x80;
Data = Data >> 1;
```

Compiler says : Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

But I successfully run this code in C taking "Data" as unsigned char.

HOW TO DO THIS IN C#?

Thank You for Help.

Comment: `Data >> 1` will be of type `int`, just convert it back to `byte`: `Data = (byte) (Data >> 1);`

Answer (score 2):

To prevent the conversion to int, you can use assignment operators instead

```
byte Data = 0x00;
Data |= 0x80;
Data >>= 1; // result is 0x40
```

Comment: I don't understand why result is 64? I think "Data or 0x80" Data become 0x80 then "Data shift to right 1 time" Data become 0x40. So result Data should be 0x40. Am I right?

Comment: Meh, that was the generic number format.  You're right.  I needed to `ToString("x")` to get the hex value.

Answer (score 1):

Cast it explicitly like:

```
byte Data = 0x00;
Data = (byte)(Data | 0x80);
Data = (byte)(Data >> 1);
```

or declare date as int and convert to byte at the end (if you are sure it fits into byte)

```
int Data = 0x00;
Data = Data | 0x80;
Data = Data >> 1;
byte bData = (byte)Data;
```